# Ada Environment Variable Path Issue

Tags: gcc, environment-variables, ada

When compiling Ada, when I change the build path to the GNAT build, all global commands (clear, sudo, gcc, etc.) don't work but when I change it to the global (default) command, the global commands work, but the Ada build isn't recognized.

How do I fix this?

**Note:** `➜  Ada` = `$`, (using Oh My Zzh from Ada folder)

Terminal: (Note start & end are the same)

```
➜  Ada gcc -c main.adb                        
error: invalid value 'ada' in '-x ada'
➜  Ada PATH=/Users/Ryan/opt/GNAT/2020/bin     
➜  Ada gcc -c main.adb                   
xcode-select: error trying to exec 'xcode-select': execvp: No such file or directory
gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
➜  Ada PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
➜  Ada gcc -c main.adb                          
error: invalid value 'ada' in '-x ada'
➜  Ada
```

Comment: errrm... Mac, right? https://forward-in-code.blogspot.com/2019/06/macos-software-development-kit-changes.html#more may help

Answer (score 5):

Just do

```
PATH=/Users/Ryan/opt/GNAT/2020/bin:${PATH}
```

instead of

```
PATH=/Users/Ryan/opt/GNAT/2020/bin
```

You need to *preppend* path to GNAT, not replace whole `PATH`.

Comment: prepend (i.e. must come first, or at least before `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`